# Automator script runs without error but does nothing?

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, script, python

I'm trying to create an automator app that will run a python script on text files that are dropped onto it.

I have the following automator app set up using the various other solutions from SO;

[image]

It runs without error, but the python script does not seem to be invoked properly, as it should be producing a text file with the analysis that my python script does. Running this directly in terminal does work as intended, so I'm not sure what's going on.

I've done a global search to see if the file is exported elsewhere, but no go; it is not generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want "Pass input: as arguments" (drop-down menu to the right of your "Run Shell Script" component) and then the following script

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/bin/python3 /Volumes/Scripts/script.py "$f"
done
```